# Binding to a property with set and get is not updating in conjunction with a range slider?

Tags: angular, ionic3

here is a stackblitz when I attempt to present a slider in seconds while I maintain it in milliseconds internally however the bound value is not updating. It works if I bind to a simple field but not property. Why not? Angular is not able to watch for it? I use props a lot to simply the templates and give them access to data that typically resides in other object/services.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-7sn3uz?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html
[image]

```
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Announce Media Delay {{AnnounceMediaDelaySeconds}} seconds</ion-label>
        <ion-range min="0" max="10" [(ngModel)]="AnnounceMediaDelaySeconds" color="secondary">
            <ion-label range-left>0</ion-label>
            <ion-label range-right>10</ion-label>
        </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
```

```
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // VIEW TEMPLATE HELPERS
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /** map to milliseconds 
     - 20200405
    */
  get AnnounceMediaDelaySeconds(): number {
    return this.AnnounceMediaDelay / 1000;
  }
  set AnnounceMediaDelaySeconds(value: number) {
    this.AnnounceMediaDelay * 1000;
  }

  // the following lives in another object/service
  // UserOptions.AnnounceMediaDelay
  AnnounceMediaDelay: number = 2000;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The set is wrong, you should put this.announce....= value × 1000 or anything to set, here you just multiplying or by 1000 but the value is not saved in it.

Comment: Oops!  Thank you my brain is shot

Comment: @MostafaHarb can you create an answer for this just to make this a complete question-answer thread?

Comment: @gerstams should I just delete it? as it was the result of a simple oversight, i mostly do cut and paste programming :) but if you think it has value I will leave it.

Comment: I'd say leave it here. Can help others that try to implement a slider just like you ;-)

Comment: @gerstams I have fixed the blitz, what's the proper way to lock the shared link before I revised it, am I expected to fork than make a change? and provide a new link?

Comment: Your welcome bro <3 . Have more focus next time *_^.

Comment: nothing in your profile, @MostafaHarb how can I reach you? perhaps you can shoot me an email at MostafaHarb(aaaaaaaat)mumti.org,

Comment: mostafa_7arb@hotmail.com, whatsapp 0096176303389

Answer (score 1):

The fix is actually quite simple it was a coding error on my part correct by  **@MostafaHarb ** below in the comment Thank You!!!.

```
  set AnnounceMediaDelaySeconds(value: number) {
    this.AnnounceMediaDelay = value * 1000;
  }
```

I have also fixed the blitz to work, as I expected it to.